# Update dictionary within dictionary dynamically return same character count for different parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to retrieve wikipedia pages' characters count, for articles in different languages. I'm using a dictionary with as key the name of the page and as value a dictionary with the language as key and the count as value.

The code is:

```
pages = ["L'arte della gioia", "Il nome della rosa"]
langs = ["it", "en"]
dicty = {}
dicto ={}
numz = 0
for x in langs:
    wikipedia.set_lang(x)
    for y in pages:
        pagelang = wikipedia.page(y)
        splittedpage = pagelang.content
        dicto[y] = dicty
        for char in splittedpage:
            numz +=1
            dicty[x] = numz
```

If I print dicto, I get

```
{"L'arte della gioia": {'it': 72226, 'en': 111647}, 'Il nome della rosa': {'it': 72226, 'en': 111647}}
```

The count should be different for the two pages.

Comment: move `dicty = {}` declaration under `for y` statement.

Comment: Then I have {"L'arte della gioia": {'en': 84971}, 'Il nome della rosa': {'en': 111647}}
but I want also it

Comment: then under `for x`

Comment: I get the same number in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. I didn't run it because I don't have the wikipedia module.

*Notes*:

1. Since your expected result is `dict[page,dict[lan,cnt]]`, I think first iterate pages is more natural, then iterate languages. Maybe for performance reason you want first iterate languages, please comment.
2. Characters count of `text` can simply be `len(text)`, why iterate and sum again?
3. Variable names. You will soon be lost in `x` `y` like variables.

```py
pages = ["L'arte della gioia", "Il nome della rosa"]
langs = ["it", "en"]
dicto = {}
for page in pages:
    lang_cnt_dict = {}
    for lang in langs:
        wikipedia.set_lang(lang)
        page_lang = wikipedia.page(page)
        chars_cnt = len(pagelang.content)
        lang_cnt_dict[lan] = chars_cnt
    dicto[page] = lang_cnt_dict
print(dicto)
```

*update*

If you want iterate langs first

```py
pages = ["L'arte della gioia", "Il nome della rosa"]
langs = ["it", "en"]
dicto = {}
for lang in langs:
    wikipedia.set_lang(lang)
    for page in pages:
        page_lang = wikipedia.page(page)
        chars_cnt = len(pagelang.content)
        if page in dicto:
            dicto[page][lang] = chars_cnt
        else:
            dicto[page] = {lang: chars_cnt}
print(dicto)
```

Comment: I want character count... not word count

Comment: whatever, it's just a variable name, its value is equal to yours.